# If statement says cell is filled when it isn't

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I am trying to load data from parse. When I have loaded the data I am trying to show different `div`s on which the data has come back.

For example I am asking JavaScript get cell data for the loaded user and then run an `if` statement to see if it is empty or full, however the `if` statement keeps saying it is full when the cell is empty can anyone help me?

```
Parse.initialize("APIKey", "APIKey");

function first() {
  console.log("Running first");

  var userSub = Parse.User.current().get("renewDate");
  if (userSub == "" || userSub == "undefined") {
    console.log("No Data found");

    $("#sub").show();
    $("#unsub").hide();
  } 
  else {
    console.log("Data Found");

    $("#sub").hide();
    $("#unsub").show();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're actually expecting the *string* `"undefined"`, you probably mean to say:

```
if (userSub == "" || userSub == undefined) {
```

both of which could be merged as:

```
if (! userSub)
```

unless `0` or `false` are valid values, in which case you want to be *very* specific:

```
if (userSub === "" || userSub === undefined) {
```

Comment: Sorry @PaulRoub about the time it took to get back to you, you have answer my question just right thanks!